# Custom Meta Box for Wordpress add a checkbox that inserts a small bit of CSS

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, metadata

I would like to add a simple meta box checkbox option to every post and page in a Wordpress site.

The text of the box:

```
'Check here to hide the slider featured text'
```

If the box is checked then it should insert the following CSS into the page:

```
.featured-text {  display: none !important;}
```

Thanks for any and all help with this.

Here is what I'm working with:
The metabox is inserting correctly and saving, but the css is not being added

```
// This section is working...

// add meta checkbox to hide featured text on the slider

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_hide_slider_text' );
function add_hide_slider_text()
{
    add_meta_box( 'hide_slider_text_checkbox', 'Hide Slider Text', 'hide_slider_text_func', 'post', 'side', 'high' );
    add_meta_box( 'hide_slider_text_checkbox', 'Hide Slider Text', 'hide_slider_text_func', 'page', 'side', 'high' );
}

function hide_slider_text_func( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $check = isset( $values['hide_slider_text_check'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['hide_slider_text_check'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_hide_slider_text_nonce', 'hide_text_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hide_slider_text_check" id="hide_slider_text_check" <?php checked( $check, 'on' ); ?> />
        <label for="hide_slider_text_check">Hide slider text overlay?</label>
    </p>
    <?php   
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'hide_text_option_save' );
function hide_text_option_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['hide_text_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['hide_text_nonce'], 'my_hide_slider_text_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
        )
    );

    // Save only if it's checked, or delete it if it's not
        if ( isset( $_POST['hide_slider_text_check'] ) && $_POST['hide_slider_text_check'] ) {
                 add_post_meta( $post_id, 'hide_slider_text_check', 'on', true );
           } else {
             delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'hide_slider_text_check' );
}
}

// this section isn't working at the moment

// now we insert the new css if the box is checked


    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hide_slider_text_check', true)) { 

    function my_styles_method() {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'custom-style',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' //if style.css is loaded then insert the css
        );


            $custom_css = "

            .featured-text {  display: none !important;}";

            wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you just make it so that when you have that option checked you display that part of the code, and when not, hide it, in php, not with css? `index.php` or `page.php` should be the files responsible for blog posts, `single.php` for single post and so on...

Comment: Can you clarify this, it sounds good, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'd try with this (this kinda looks like what I'm doing when I'm fixing my themes :D)

```
function hide_slider_text_func( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $hide_slider_text_check = (isset( $values['hide_slider_text_check'] ) && $values['hide_slider_text_check'][0] == 1? 1 : 0;
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_hide_slider_text_nonce', 'hide_text_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="hide_slider_text_check" id="hide_slider_text_check" value="1" <?php checked( $hide_slider_text_check, 1); ?> />Hide slider text overlay?</label>
    </p>
    <?php   
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'hide_text_option_save' );
function hide_text_option_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['hide_text_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['hide_text_nonce'], 'my_hide_slider_text_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
        )
    );

    $hide_slider_text_check = (isset($_POST["hide_slider_text_check"])) ? $_POST["hide_slider_text_check"]==1 ? 1 : 0;
    update_post_meta($post_id, "hide_slider_text_check", $hide_slider_text_check);

}
}
```

After that, depending on how you have defined your `'opt_name'` value, you first define in your theme where you want it to execute, on the top of your php file `global $opt_name` and say `$custom_data = get_post_custom();` then in front of your slider you can add

```
<?php if(isset($custom_data ['hide_slider_text_check'][0]) && $custom_data ['hide_slider_text_check'][0]==1): ?>

//your code goes here

<?php endif; ?>
```

If I haven't made any big errors, this should made the code in between the `if` part run only if you have checked the option for it. My saving metabox is a bit different so there could be a problem, but I don't think it should have to make any problems.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but with your code I would need to wrap the slider include in your php IF statement?

In my case, and why I was trying to do it by inserting the css, is that the theme I'm working with has about 10 page templates and the slider is hooked into them. If possible I want to find a solution without having to edit or create additional page templates.

Comment: Yup, you're correct. I find it efficient this way, because if you don't want it to show, your site won't load any unnecessary html. With display:none, the html is still there. You don't have to do it this way, ofc, but I find it somewhat a better solution ;) And editing 10 template files isn't a big deal :) I recommend sublime text as an editor. It has tons of additions that can speed up code writing (emmet snippets etc...)

Comment: Agreed, I like the clean way without extra html. Since the page templates are not actually files, but are being created with hooks and functions, outside of the themes' functions.php, in this case I'd still rather do all the work from the child theme's functions file.

(Upvote because your solution will work, but not quite the solution I'm looking for.)

Comment: Oh, you're hooking them, I understand now why you'd rather use css approach :D